# use pipe operator in mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I am wondering with the following code does not work. Because pipe is not compatible in mutate?

```
tibble(x = c(1,2), y = c(3,4)) %>% 
mutate(z = {. %>% (function(tb) {tb$x + tb$y})})
```

I know a workaround is

```
tibble(x = c(1,2), y = c(3,4)) %>% 
    mutate(z = map_depth(., .depth = 0, function(tb) {tb$x + tb$y}))
```

or

```
tibble(x = c(1,2), y = c(3,4)) %>% 
    mutate(z = exec(function(tb) {tb$x + tb$y}, .))
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't simply use `%>% mutate(z = x + y)` ?

Comment: @Jrm_FRL This is just an example. The real function is more complicated (cannot be done in vector manner).

Comment: This works: `mutate(z = {(function(tb) {tb$x + tb$y})(.)})`, but you probably want to use some flavor of `map` function, is my guess.

Comment: I think you may need `tibble(x = c(1,2), y = c(3,4)) %>%
 mutate(z = map2_dbl(x, y, sum))`.

Comment: @Adam - what is the `(.)` operation in your answer?  I've seen it in Stackoverflow solutions, but I haven't run across it in my R reference books.  And Googling '(.)' isn't fruitful.  Where could I read more about it?

Comment: @DavidT I am trying to figure it out exactly. I think it might be forcing `rlang` to evaluate the `.` and therefore it gets converted to a tibble rather than a function and is thus interpretable by the pipe. I don't know and that is just a wild guess.

Comment: @Adam  the "dot" or "period" character is used to refer to the placement of the input to a pipe operator. the parenthesis `()` immediately after an `anynomyous function` is used to pass arguments to the function. In combination, OP here is using `(.)` to pass the input to the pipe as argument to the anonymous function. you can read more at https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works as you are expecting:

```r
tibble(x = c(1,2), y = c(3,4)) %>% 
  mutate(z = {(.) %>% (function(tb) {tb$x + tb$y})})

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#       x     y     z
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     3     4
# 2     2     4     6
```

The problem isn't the pipe, but rather that `.` seems to be interpreted as a function (which throws off the pipe).

---

**Edit:**

@Aramis7d provided a link to the documentation for [magrittr](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html) in a comment. The relevant line is:

> #### Using the dot-place holder as lhs
>
> When the dot is used as lhs, the result will be a functional sequence, i.e. a function which applies the entire chain of right-hand sides in turn to its input. See the examples.

So in your example, you were trying to assign an entire function to `z` within the mutate. You can see this based on the error message returned. By using `(.)`, we force evaluation of the `.` and get results as expected.

```r
tibble(x = c(1,2), y = c(3,4)) %>% 
  mutate(z = {. %>% (function(tb) {tb$x + tb$y})})
# Error: Column `z` is of unsupported type function
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting scenario indeed.

Without any more specific use cases, this seems like the `%>%` operator is not at all required even if you want to use `anonymous functions` within the `mutate()` .

```
tibble(x = c(1,2), y = c(3,4)) %>% 
  mutate(z = {(function(tb){tb$x + tb$y})(.)})
```

returns:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      x     y     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     3     4
2     2     4     6
```